# Iam getting error find a diffr supporting object of type string and NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

Here iam try to getting the data in html input field using angular but i getting error.if you know the suggestion please let me know.below iam sharing the code.

```
<p *ngFor="let result of data">
    <input  class="form1 validation-field form-control" style="position:absolute;top:10.85in;left:0.92in;width:1.56in;height:0.19in" src="assets/img/ri_341.png"  formControlName="taxid" [(ngModel)]="this[result]"/>
</p>
```

here is form.ts code

```
public  insPrevalue() {
    this.batchService. insPrevalue().subscribe((resp)=>{
        this.data = resp;
        console.log(1129)
        console.log( this.data)
    }
}
```

here iam sending the data like to backend:

[{"25(A)":"123456","33(A)":"123456"}]

Comment: `this.data` is not an array according to that error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `this.data` initialize as an array.

```
data: your_type[] = []
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion.but how can i getting the data in input field

Comment: Don't use the parenthesis on object key names. It will throw an error when we try to pass the value.

Comment: try strings like `[{"name":"123456","value":"123456"}]` and then bind to the ngModel  `[(ngModel)]="result.name"`

Comment: iam getting error this one Error trying to diff '[{"25(A)":"123456","33(A)":"123456"}]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: [(ngModel)]="result.name" this is possible to getting the value backend